# Create a Racket prop:custom-write that prints like #:transparent

Tags: data-structures, racket

I have written the following struct definition:

```
> (require racket/struct)
> (struct/contract foo
    ([bar (listof number?)])
    #:property prop:custom-write
    (make-constructor-style-printer
      (lambda _ 'fiz)
      (lambda (self) (list (map add1 (foo-bar self))))))
```

When I print an instance, it seems at first to print fine, but when I put that instance into a list, it prints surrounded by `#< ... >`:

```
> (foo '(1 2 3))
(fiz '(2 3 4))
> `(,(foo '(1 2 3)))
'(#<fiz: (2 3 4)>)
```

What I would expect to happen is for it to print like the struct below:

```
> (struct/contract biz
    ([bar (listof number?)])
    #:transparent)
> (biz '(1 2 3))
(biz '(1 2 3))
> `(,(biz '(1 2 3)))
(list (biz '(1 2 3)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation of `make-constructor-style-printer`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structutils.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstruct..rkt%29._make-constructor-style-printer%29%29):

> Note that the printer uses a separate property, prop:custom-print-quotable, to determine whether a struct instance is quotable. If so, the printer may print it in write mode it in certain contexts, *such as within a list*.

So you need to set [the `prop:custom-print-quotable` property](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Printer_Extension.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._prop%7E3acustom-print-quotable%29%29) too to get the behavior you're looking for:

```lisp
(struct/contract foo
 ([bar (listof number?)])
 #:property prop:custom-write
 (make-constructor-style-printer
  (lambda _ 'fiz)
  (lambda (self) (list (map add1 (foo-bar self)))))
 #:property prop:custom-print-quotable 'never)
```

Examples of use:

```lisp
> (define x (foo '(1 2 3))
> (list x) ; uses print
(list (fiz '(2 3 4)))
> (writeln (list x)) ; write isn't affected
(#<fiz: (2 3 4)>)
```

Comment: Great!  Just to add to this, `display` has the same behavior as `write`.  So, as a followup question if you had `(struct bar (biz) #:transparent)` and `(write (bar 1))` you get `#(struct:bar 1)`.  Note the parentheses vs angle brackets, and the prefix `struct:`.  Is it possible to replicate this behavior using `prop:custom-write`?

Comment: Also, as another note, as it says in the doc, if you want to understand the details of the values for `prop:custom-print-quotable` (`'self`, `'never`, `'maybe`, and `'always`), take a look at [The Printer](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/printing.html).